# Solving the cycloid equation

Tags: cycloid

The equations are:

$x=r(t-\sin{t})$

$y=r(1-\cos{t})$

Lets say that $(x,y)=(1,2)$ for a point. How can I find the radius of the cycloid?
I can't solve the mathematics equation:
$$\frac{1}{t-\sin{t}}=\frac{2}{1-\cos{t}}$$

It's complicate for me to solve it.
If I'll find it I would find $r$.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you have the equation $$1-\cos(t)=2t-2\sin(t)$$ then $t=0$ is one solution the other solution can be obtained by a numerical method, $$t\approx 1.401379455902473454923964650592$$

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted to know. How you solved it? I'll be glad if you have an explanation for the full solution

Comment: there is the Newton-Raphson method Google for it

Comment: OK, but what will be my start number (t0) in this case?

Comment: take your calculator plot the equation and you will get a startnumber

Comment: And for a more global case, if want the shortest trajectory from a to b according to the cycloid solution, the radios will be figure from (x,y) of a or b?